# Flutter ListView in StateLess Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

as I learned , in `StateLessWidget` we can't call any thing like `setState` to rebuild the widget tree and so on.

but when we scroll a `listVeiw` , the position and ... will change.
but as we in `StatelessWidget` , I don't know why it is possible to change the State of `STL` because the `ListView` has its own offset state and it can change and reflected in User Interface .

Comment: no , I don't use any ```STF``` in my case but I don't know why we can scroll on to the screen because I am using only ```STL``` widgets. THANKS

Comment: `ListView` is also a widget with its own class and everything, and many of those classes are implemented as `StatefulWidget`, so it has no problem updating its own state.

Comment: You can scroll because the ListView uses ScrollOffset and pre-defined viewport with a set height and width. The ListView, the ScrollBar and the GridView use the available viewport with Future builder objects i.e. only the ones which are on-screen maintain the state and which are not on-screen are either destroyed if they were on-screen at some time or not yet have been created. These things don't have any effect on STL or STF widgets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView is a stateful widget. 
Just because you wrap it in a stateless widget does not mean it also becomes stateless.

That's the whole magic, you can have many stateful and stateless widgets wrapped in stateful and stateless widgets...

Comment: It sounds like it must be stateful, but the inheritance hierarchy says it is Stateless: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html. Must be magic ;-)